# Multiple forms in one page in DJANGO

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I've been developing a django project for 1 month. So I'm new at Django. My current problem with Django is; When I have multiple forms in one page and the page is submitted for a form, the other forms field values are lost. Because they are not posted.
I've found a solution for this problem;

- When there is get method, I send the other forms value with the page url and I can handle them from the get request.
- When there is post method, I keep the others form fields value in
  hidden inputs in HTML side in the form which is posted. Hence I
  can handle it from the post request.

Maybe I can keep them in session object. But it may not be good to keep them for whole time which the user logg in. But I dont know. I may have to use this method.

Is there another way which is more effective to keep all forms fields in Django?

Any Suggestion?

Thank!

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of AJAX for a single form submission instead of whole page submit.

Comment: Yes, AJAX may be tought as a solution but sometimes AJAX may make system complex. Without ajax there should be  better solution than the solutions given in question.